# Outside of the values range of for linear model

Tags: r

I have 12 values. For each month one.
Using them wants to predict the next 12 months, using linear model.

my operation does not work

```
> fit <- lm(g[c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)]  ~ rep(1997, each = 12) + rep(1:12, 1))
> cpi2011 <- fit$coefficients[[1]] + fit$coefficients[[2]] * 1998 + fit$coefficients[[3]] * (1:12)
> plot(cpi2011)
Error in plot.window(...) : 'ylim' needs a finite value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

> plot(fit) # gives nonsense
```

please help :)

Comment: What is your `g` object?

Comment: One does not predict using linear model outside the range.

Comment: Indifferently. Each value is the normal number e.g. 1, 4, 3.4 etc.

Comment: @David Arenburg - it is not clear to me...

Comment: You shouldn't extrapolate outside the x range. This is not what OLS is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you add: `rep(1997, each = 12)` to your linear-model, your design-matrix will not have full rank. This is handled by R by setting the coefficient to ´NA´. Try looking at `coef(fit)`.

Just remove `rep(1997, each = 12)` from the linear-model, eg.:

```
fit <- lm(g[c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23)]  ~ rep(1:12, 1))
cpi2011 <- fit$coefficients[1] + fit$coefficients[2] * (12+(1:12))
plot(cpi2011)
```

Comment: then the prediction code would have to change to `fit$coefficients[[1]] +  fit$coefficients[[2]] * (12+(1:12))`

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker. I should of course have made my answer a little more complete from the start. Too fast too lazy...